# Error: Property map does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type ''

```
this.db.object('/chat').valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{data.map(elem=>{
    this.messages.push(elem)
  })
});
```

Comment: Apparently `data` isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an array operator on an object. {} indicates it's an object. While [] are arrays. Try just pushing the data directly.`this.messages.push(data)`